# How to determine the current boundaries of a WPF canvas?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

The images that my applications render on a WPF Canvas have widely varied dimensions. I prefer to scale/shift them so they precisely fit the current canvas, which may have been resized by the user.

How can I retrieve the canvas borders?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look in the XAML and find the **ancestor** of your Canvas (maybe further up the ancestor chain). One of them contains the **ActualWidth** and **ActualHeight**

Your are welcome.